# General proof of power rule

Tags: calculus

I am confused about how the textbook I am using (aimed at social scientists) proves the power rule for the "general n", which I assume means for all real numbers. The book writes the following:

> For more general *n*, the easiest way to see the [proof of the power rule for all real numbers] is to use a slightly different definition of the derivative. Consider the derivative at a point *c*. The *x* approaches *c*, the difference *c* – *x* goes to zero, just as *h* does. So let *h* = *c* – *x*. Then the derivative definition becomes:
>   $$
> f'(c) = \lim_{x \to c}  \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}
> $$

Can anyone explain to me the steps of finding this new definition of the derivative? Given
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$
when I substitute *h* with *c* – *x* I get
$$
f'(c) = \lim_{x \to c}  \frac{f(c)-f(x)}{c-x}
$$

I cannot for the life of me understand how the book calculated their derivative definition. While I know there are other proofs of the power rule for real numbers I would like to understand how theirs was calculated. Many thanks.
\\\\
As it turns out this has a very easy answer that I somehow missed, but I am leaving it up for posterity. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Both definitions do the same thing: the derivative is the slope of the tangent at $c$; for a point arbitrarily close to $c$ (which is at $c+h$), we can think of the curve $y=f(x)$ between these points as being (almost) linear and calculate it for the line-segment joining $(c,f(c))$ and $(c+h,f(c+h))$.

Comment: In the question, you should replace "my book" by the book in question. Otherwise it appears that you wrote the book.

Answer (score 2):

$$  \frac{f(c) - f(x)}{c-x} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{-1}{-1}}_{{}=1}  = \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}  \text{.}  $$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the definition of derivative given by your book is *equivalent* to the usual one, thanks to the change of variable in the limit. You have used $h=c-x$: if you multiply numerator and denominator by $-1$, then you will get precisely the same limit of your book. Another possible change of variable is $h=x-c$, which gives the same result.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now - glad to see it was a simple missing step (on my end).

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little more subtle than it appears, because the substitution actually is performed incorrectly and only coincidentally comes up with something equivalent to the correct answer.

You start with
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.
$$

If you now substitute $c - x$ in each place that $h$ appears, you get
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{c - x \to 0}  \frac{f(x+c - x)-f(x)}{c - x}.
$$
Simplifying,
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{c \to x}  \frac{f(c)-f(x)}{c - x}.
$$

Note that the left-hand side has not changed at all, because there was (of course) no $h$ there to begin with. You **cannot** get $f'(c)$ on the left side of this equation (as you claim you did in the question) simply by making the substitution $h = c - x$,
because $x \neq c$.

Note also that I wrote $\lim_{c \to x}$ on the right-hand side, not
$\lim_{x \to c}$, because $x$ is the given quantity on the left, not $c$.
It makes no sense to say that a given quantity ($x$) approaches some other quantity ($c$) that mysteriously appears from nowhere.

A correct derivation is as follows. Start with
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.
$$

First substitute $c$ for $x$:
$$
f'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}.
$$
Now substitute $x - c$ in place of $h$:
$$
f'(c) = \lim_{x - c \to 0}  \frac{f(c+x - c)-f(c)}{x - c}.
$$

This simplifies to
$$
f'(c) = \lim_{x \to c}  \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x - c},
$$
as stated in the textbook.

The key thing to understand here is that the symbol $x$ does not have a fixed meaning in mathematics, but takes its meaning only from the way it is used in an equation.
Since the book did not use $x$ when writing the formula "$f'(c)$" on the left-hand side of its equation, we cannot assume $x$ on the right-hand side has the same role it plays in the definition of $f'(x)$.
Instead, the role played by $x$ when defining $f'(x)$ is played by $c$ instead, and $x$ (if it is used) plays a different role.